# How to prevent the boot-stopper: Give root password for maintenance (or press Control-D to continue):

Tags: debian-wheezy

I would like to prevent a server from hanging at reboot prompting for root password or ctrl+D in case of a disk event. The below guide appears outdated, since on my Debian Wheezy don't have a `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file, but then what?

http://www.tomatosoft.biz/blog/2012/01/21/avoid-boot-stopper-give-root-password-for-maintenance/

Comment: That's a bad idea. That pause is in there for a reason, so you can inspect the system before doing something potentially destructive like fsck.

Comment: It's equally evil that the system stops upon boot so it cannot be inspected remotely.

Answer (score 1):

your OS is using grub2.
In grub2 there is no /boot/grub/menu.lst. It has been replaced by /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

Comment: Right, so the fix proposed in the link above does not work with grub2 configuration?

Comment: Grub2 still preserved quite options and many more from grub. Refer to grub2 manual http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html#mozTocId624480 It explains lots of things.